# Are metaclasses objects?

Tags: python, definition, metaclass

I always hear or read that 'everything in Python is an object'. This sentence is really helpful for beginner programmers as myself, and I was quickly able to understand that classes, methods are objects.

However, when trying to understand the mechanism of class creation a bit deeper, I've stumbled upon the concept of metaclasses and this brilliant question was able to unveil almost everything that I didn't know about classes:
[What are metaclasses in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python;)

Now I know that instances of metaclasses are classes, and instances of classes are instances(?)/objects(?). The repetitive use of the word object boggles me, so I will call the instances of a class also instances, since classes are objects too. This reasoning concludes us to my question: Are metaclasses also objects? What is the exact definition of an object?

I assume that metaclasses are objects. Since they have attributes, they have their parent classes, so they are themselves instances of classes.

Comment: Of course they are. Metaclasses are themselves classes, and [classes are objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949). This is already answer in the question you linked (and even more thoroughly in the duplicate target).

Comment: Yes, metaclasses are objects, Classes are a kind of object, and metaclasses are a kind of class. Specifically, classes are objects **that represent the type of** other objects, and a metaclass is simply a class whose instances are themselves classes. This is covered by what you linked. The remaining actual question is "what does it mean to say that something 'is an object'?"; I've linked a duplicate for that. The short version is that, yes, you correctly understand the necessary test for "being an object".

Comment: Metaclasses, being objects, are instances of classes; specifically, they are instances of the class named `type`, which is the default metaclass (i.e., class) for classes, **including itself**. When you create a different metaclass, as explained in the link you found, it should normally be a subclass of `type`. (I did not write this as an answer because it follows automatically from the already linked information.)